# what is the major differences of job talks given by graduate/postdoc and assistant professor/above?

Tags: application, faculty-application

There are a lot material on suggestions/advices for job talks for those graduate students and postdocs to seek a first assistant professor position. However, there is less advices about job talk for assistant professor or above, seeking other positions like assistant/associate professor position, either due to moving to a better school/trying for early tenure or other reasons.

To summarise, usually for first AP application, a job talk consist of 1) background explaining concepts, then 2) in-deep discussions on 1-2 projects, and 3) some future directions.

My question is what are the differences for the job talk given by assistant professor or above, compared to those apply for the first AP position? Can we just follow the usual suggestions, with some slight modifications or there should be a complete change of structure?

Answer (score 1):

Are you currently an assistant professor? Have you given invited lectures at other universities?

Presumably you have talked about the direction of your research group, provided contextual background, and delved into some exciting projects/results?

That is generally going to be your main talk.

Your search committee will direct you as to whether you should include future research plans as part of your main talk or as a separate one. Here (large R1), we have two talks. An open current research, and a closed proposed research/future directions talk. In the past, we have had three talks, including a teaching one which I thought was a bit much to ask a candidate to prep three separate ones.

When we interview postdocs we are more likely to probe their proposal harder because it is all just a proposal. With established faculty, it's more a discussion about how it will fit. It is very hard to get an interview for an associate/full position if you aren't already doing well at the assistant/associate level. So at that point it's not about pressing you on future research as you are already established. It's more about seeing how it all comes together with our departmental needs/resources.

Comment: I am an assistant professor and applying an assistant professor in a better university. Yes, I did the same and also some AP candidates who want to move to my university also did the same.